# c# TCP Server Client Threading Issies

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient, tcp, tcplistener

Here is the problem,
I have below scenario coded.

1. A TCP Listener running in thread A connecting to a Client 1
2. A Second TCP Listener running in thread B Connecting to multiple clients each in a different thread. By this I mean as soon as a client is
   accepted in thread B, A different thread is created for further
   processing of the client where it waits to get data from "TCP
   Listener B" in a while loop

**What I want to do and where I'm facing problem is,**

I want to pass data recieved from Thread 1 by the Client 1 to clients in thread 2.

**What I believe is happening**,

Since I'm in Thread 1 when I get data from Client 1 in Thread 1, when I try sending data to clients in thread 2, I always get connection false.

Is this a threading issue?

How can I overcome it issue?

[image: TCP Connection]

**EDIT**

It's a windows form application

Both the TCP Listener run in same application.

I'm maintaining a list of TcpClients that connect to TCP Listener B and when I get some data from thread A, I get the TCP Client from this list that I maintain and try to send the data, but cannot as connection state becomes false.

Comment: It would be simpler to not use threads but rather use async sockets. And for this data transfer you can just use events.

Comment: _How_ do you want to communicate? Over a port? Or is this all in one memory-space?

Comment: @ Henk all this is in one memory space

Comment: @sami I tried this using acceptclient and beginread callbacks, but for some reason when I debug, the receive functions are are fired, but when I try without debugging, the the receive callbacks are never fired!!!!

Comment: Well, what can we say without code? The diagram is very helpful though. In general socket programming is very hard and using async IO without await adds a big load of problems on top of it.

Comment: The Code is a bit too much to show here so I decided to put the diagram, I will give async methods another try. But I would like to know whether  I'm getting connection property of clients in thread B false because I'm trying to send message to that client from a different thread?

Comment: Architecturally this is fine. The choice of using threads to handle clients is also totally fine assuming there aren't too many. Sockets are thread-safe in the sense that you can access them from different threads. Your code must have a bug and it cannot be found without seeing that particular piece of code. Clone the solution and delete everything not strictly necessary. That should result in a small snippet that can be posted here.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, so i used a backgroundworker instead of a thread to handle the Clients. Here is the extracted code from my project:

```
 private static void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        listener.Start();
        while (!bw.CancellationPending)
        {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, client);
        }
        listener.Stop();
    }
```

And in ThreadProc its just handling every client

```
private static void ThreadProc(object state)
    {
        var client = (TcpClient)state;
        clientsList.Add(client);
        handleClient hclient = new handleClient();
        hclient.startClient(client); //Do whatever with your client here
    }
```

And to broadcast information i did this

```
public static void broadcast(byte[] msg, string uName)
    {
        foreach (TcpClient Item in clientsList)
        {
            if (Item != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    TcpClient broadcastSocket;
                    broadcastSocket = Item;
                    NetworkStream broadcastStream = broadcastSocket.GetStream();
                    Byte[] broadcastBytes = null;

                    broadcastBytes = msg;

                    Debug.WriteLine("Send Data to everyone from " + uName);
                    broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length);
                    broadcastStream.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //Handle exceptions ....
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

i hope his helps. You can look at the finished project at https://github.com/hrkrx/MontagsmalerVS the examples are from the HostController.cs

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, you are using threads and a Winform with socket servers and socket clients, and it could make that socket gets blocked.

Try to use a single thread to attend all your TCPListeners and TCPClients, using asynchronous methods which help to avoid socket blocking:

- For TcpListener use the method: [AcceptSocketAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocketasync(v=vs.110).aspx).
- For TcpClients use the [NetworkStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx) to use the BeginRead and BeginWrite. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327534/c-sharp-high-cpu-usage-on-listener-thread-sleeping-misses-disconnect/43332998#43332998) i show how i used them.