# C# High CPU usage on Listener thread, sleeping misses disconnect

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, tcplistener, tcpserver

My connection handler is below (this is more for personal experimentation than production code)

If I don't add a Thread.Sleep anywhere in the while loop, it starts sucking down CPU.. Conversely, if I do Sleep to alleviate the endless while-spam, I miss the disconnection.. The CPU goes up in direct proportion to the number of clients/threads running, so it's not the listener itself that's causing the high usage, it's the actual client thread posted below.. Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

(I'm avoiding await-based solutions as I'm not familiar enough with async/await and the threaded method is working fine for this rather small project)

I only briefly searched around SO looking for a solution and didn't notice any that were this specific problem or that provided a solution other than directing folks to async/await articles, so sorry if I did miss an applicable answer.

```
        private void HandleConnection(CancellationToken ct) {
        int recv = 0;
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        Trace.WriteLine($"{_name} Connected");
        if (_ns.CanWrite && _client.Connected) {
            _ns.Write(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes("■WEL"), 0, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes("■WEL").Length);
            try {
                while (_client.Connected && !ct.IsCancellationRequested) {

                    while (!_ns.DataAvailable) { //first attempted solution
                        Thread.Sleep(100); // miss discon if i sleep here
                        }

                    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) {
                        Trace.WriteLine($"{(string)this} thread aborting");
                        break;
                        }

                    buf = new byte[4096];

                    if (_client.Connected && _ns.DataAvailable) {

                        recv = _ns.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                        } else {
                        recv = 0;
                        }

                    if (recv > 0) {

                        string r = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(buf);
                        r = r.TrimEnd('\0');
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(r) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r))
                            r = null; //need the !not version
                        else
                            if (ParseMsg(r))
                                break;
                        }

                    //Thread.Sleep(100); // also miss discon here too

                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) { }
            Trace.WriteLine($"{_name} Disconnected");
            if (OnDisconnected != null)
                OnDisconnected(this);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should consider using `async/await` variants

Comment: What do you mean you miss the disconnect? Are you saying that the client is still connected after it disconnects and you are stuck in the first `while` loop?

Comment: @TyCobb Yes- What I mean by missing the disconnect is the remote connection sends "■DSC" and drops, then ParseMsg(r) sees that and gracefully closes the connection.. But if the while-thread above has a Sleep(), it never gets the message. Also, _client.Connected never switches to false even after the remote client has dropped.

Comment: I've spent most of the day/night trying to find a waiting/continuous async server that isn't the typical exampled "connect, receive, echo-back, disconnect" and thus still have the problem of adding a while-loop + sleep missing incoming data.

Comment: I ended up taking the time to learn the async method and went with that. When I've cleaned it up and it's worthy of preservation here on SO, I'll answer my own question. Thanks for taking the time to respond folks, greatly appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problema than you but I found that the best way to solve this problem is:

**Not Blocking the Socket with sleeps and thread.**

**UPGRADE**: *If you use threads and sleeps into your server, it will suffer a low performance to receive and answer each message by each connection.*

If you want an High Performance App you must not use sleeps or create thread for each connection that you accept. The best way is using the Asyncronous methods that NetworkStream provides, using `BeginRead` and `EndRead`, for example:

```
    public void run()
    {
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        server.Start();

        log.Info("Starting SocketServer on Port [" + port + "]");

        while (keepRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient socket = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                if (keepRunning)
                    RequestManager.createRequestForEvalue(socket, idLayout);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.Message);
                log.Error(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        log.Info("Server Stoped.");
    }

    public static bool createRequestForEvalue(TcpClient socket, int idLayout)
    {
        Request req = null;
        req = new Request(socket,idLayout);

        registerRequest(req.ID,req); //Registra el Request, para su posterior uso.

        // DO NOT CREATE THREADS FOR ATTEND A NEW CONNECTION!!!
        //Task.Factory.StartNew(req.RunForIVR);
        //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(req.RunForIVR);

        req.startReceiveAsync(); //Recive data in asyncronus way.
        return true;
    }

    public void startReceiveAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            log.Info("[" + id + "] Starting to read the Request.");
            requestBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            NetworkStream nst = socket.GetStream();
            nst.BeginRead(requestBuffer, 0,BUFFER_SIZE, this.requestReceived, nst);
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("[" + id + "] There was a problem to read the Request: " + ex.Message);
            RequestManager.removeRequest(id);
            closeSocket();
        }
    }

    public void requestReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        try
        {   
        NetworkStream nst = socket.GetStream();
        int bread = nst.EndRead(ar); //Block the socket until all the buffer has been available.
        message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(requestBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            log.Info("[" + id + "] Request recived: [" + message +"]");
            RunForIVR();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("[" + id + "] There was a problem to read the Request: " + ex.Message);
            RequestManager.removeRequest(id);
            closeSocket();
        }

    }

    public void SendResponse(String Response)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(Response);
        sb.Append('\0', BUFFER_SIZE - Response.Length);
        string message = sb.ToString();

        log.Info("[" + id + "] ivrTrans CMD: [" + idCMD + "] RESPONSE: [" + Response + "]");

        NetworkStream nst = socket.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
            buffer[i] = (byte)message.ElementAt(i);

        nst.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, this.closeSocket, nst);
    }

    public void closeSocket(IAsyncResult ar = null)
    {

        try
        {
            if (ar != null) //Since 4.24
            {
                NetworkStream nst = socket.GetStream();
                nst.EndWrite(ar);
            }

            socket.Close();
            socket = null;
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.Warn("[" + id + "] There was a problem to close the socket. Error: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        log.Info("[" + id + "] Socket closed.");
    }
```

> **Upgrade** I use the `EndRead` to be sure that the request has been arrived at all.

By Other way, you can use `BeginWrite` and `EndWrite` to know when the socket has been finished of write to close the connection

In this way you are attended the connection in a continues way and as soon as possible. In my case i reduce the CPU usage from 30% to 0%, for an a mount of 15K request per hour.

Comment: *"In this sample i don't use `EndRead` because i don't need"* -- How do you know how many bytes were read or if there was an exception?

Comment: @acelent My protocol definition set a size of 612 bytes per request and response. When you are working with sockets and you are the owner of protocol it's a good practice to build a protocol with a header which has the amount of data to receive or, in this case,  set the a unique amount of data to send and receive (I'm not the owner of this protocol).

Comment: If you header has the size of data you can invoke two times the `BegineRead`. First to get the Header: `startReceiveAsync ` it is invoking `nst.BeginRead(requestBuffer, 0,HEADER_SIZE, this.headerReceived, nst);`, Second, and into the method `headerReceived` get the amount of data and ask for the remain bytes `nst.BeginRead(requestBuffer, 0,DataSize, this.requestReceived, nst);` Where `DataSize`is the amount of data that you get from header.

Comment: I'm not criticizing your protocol.  Without `EndRead`, you have no way to know if the read was successful, and in case it was, if it actually read as many bytes as requested.  This is wishful thinking, equivalent to the synchronous `try { nst.Read(requestBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE); } catch { }`.

Comment: @acelent I'm agree with you about the use of EndRead than i recomended it. In my case i receive a request and send a response before close the connection. I was making many tests to decide if I let or remove the EndRead and, according with my result in lab and production I decide remove EndRead, because it was enough to receive the amount of bytes of the request. But as you comment, for this answer it's better let EndRead to show how to work it.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to communicate over a socket is:

1. Continuously read. These reads will block until data comes in or until the socket is gracefully disconnected (detectable by a read completing with 0 bytes read).
2. Periodically write. [These writes are required to ensure the connection is still viable](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html).

A proper threading approach requires *two* threads per connection. I'm not convinced that it's simpler than an asynchronous approach.

P.S. If your code uses `Connected`, then it has a bug. Proper solutions never need to use `Connected`.

Comment: Appreciate the time taken to respond, and even briefly viewing your article, your response is more of a "you're wrong" and not "here's an example- or resource- of a proper way to do things via threading."

Comment: @MisterNad: There are no examples or resources that use a threading approach, because it's inherently unscalable. The best overall resource, as noted in my blog post series, is Stevens' *TCP/IP Illustrated*.