# C#: I have 100 clients to thread separately, what is the most effective way to send/receive data?

Tags: c#, multithreading, object, tcp, udp

I'm doing a project with one Server and a Client for simulation purpose. The objective is to develop a single Server that can communicate with 100 clients at a same time using TCP and UDP. I am using TCPListener and UDPClient for both Server and Client. And I am using multi threading, creating an object class.

My code has 2 problems:

1. During the run, UDP packet gets lost, which freezes some of the threads.
2. The sending/receiving speed for UDP is immensely different (Thread 2 sent 2000 vs Thread 4 sent 900 etc)

Also, when I run 10 Threads, it will work perfectly fine. But when the number of threads increases, it will throw these problems.

I have the following bits of code ↓

Client (receiving function):

```
rpacket = new byte[1024];
            //#0: UDP packet timeout
            // is this necessary?? I could use while loop to measure waiting time.
            net.tClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
            net.client.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
            //net.client.Client.SendTimeout = 2000;

            // #1: message
            _logIt(false, localThreadId, "started receivedata for threadid" + localThreadId);

            // #2: number of received data recording
            int nReceived = 0;

            // #3: loop runs forever...
            while (true)
            {

                // receiving data
                bool recursion = false;
                int recursionCount = 0;
                int bytesReceived = 0;

                // receiving data
                bytesReceived = messageReceive(out recursion);

                while (recursion == true)
                {
                    // check if there are data 3 times
                    bytesReceived = messageReceive(out recursion);
                    recursionCount++;

                    if (recursionCount <= 3)
                    {
                        if (recursionCount == 1 && rIndex > 0)
                        { rIndex--; }
                        // resend message
                        if (net.q[rIndex][1] == 0x00)
                        {

                            // sending data to PICS
                            // changed net.q[rIndex].Length - 1 to changed net.q[rIndex].Length - 2
                            try
                            {
                                int nBytesSend = net.client.Send(tempData, tempData.Length, net.ipEndPoint);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                            }

                        }

                        // if 0x01, the protocl is TCP
                        else if (net.q[rIndex][1] == 0x01)
                        {
                            try { 
                            int nBytesSend = net.tClient.Client.Send(tempData, tempData.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else if (recursionCount == 4)
                    {

                        // hoot~ byebye 
                        recursion = false;
                        Usage("hoot");

                    }
                }
            }
```

Client (sending function):

```
// if 0x00, the protocol is UDP

                    if (net.q[rIndex][1] == 0x00)
                    {

                        // sending data to PICS
                        // changed net.q[rIndex].Length - 1 to changed net.q[rIndex].Length - 2
                        int nBytesSend = net.client.Send(data, net.q[rIndex].Length - 2, net.ipEndPoint);

                    }

                    // if 0x01, the protocl is TCP

                    else if (net.q[rIndex][1] == 0x01)
                    {

                        int nBytesSend = net.tClient.Client.Send(data, net.q[rIndex].Length - 2, SocketFlags.None);
                    }

                    // June 1th, tempData is only used for failed messages
                    if (data.Length != 0)
                    { tempData = data; }
                    Array.Resize(ref tempData, data.Length);


                    net.nSent++;
                    totalSent[localThreadId]++;
                    if (verbosity)
                        _logIt(false, localThreadId, "# of data sent: " + net.nSent);

                    // after sending, set the queue[][0] to 0x00
                    net.q[rIndex][0] = 0x00;
                    // setting queue[][1] is not neccessary...
                    rIndex++;
```

Message Receive(out recursion):

```
messageReceive(out bool audi)
        {
            int numBytes = 0;
            audi = false;
            // updated try and catch method, because there can be udp or tcp
            try
            {

                rpacket = net.client.Receive(ref net.ipEndPoint);
                numBytes = rpacket.Length;

            }

            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    numBytes = net.tClient.Client.Receive(rpacket);
                    Array.Resize(ref rpacket, numBytes);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    audi = true;
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                }


            }

            return numBytes;
        }
```

Server side is same as the client.

FYI: there is a 2-D byte array called queue that stores all of the data that will be sent to the remote user. wIndex is a integer that is used for writing the reply data to the queue. rIndex is a integer that is used for reading the reply data from the queue and sends it to the remote user.

How can I fix my problems?

Comment: 100 threads is only useful if you have 100 cores to do work on. You should look in to asyncronous methods to send and receive and not create any threads at all.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ok I will do that. By the way, can I use task instead?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "use task" if you mean `Task.Run(` no you can't you still are creating threads. If you mean switching from `int nBytesSend = net.client.Send(tempData, tempData.Length, net.ipEndPoint)` to [`int nBytesSend = await net.client.SendAsync(tempData, tempData.Length, net.ipEndPoint)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194200(v=vs.110).aspx) then yes, using tasks is a great way to do async. If you have to write a `Task.Run(` in your code you are making a mistake in your networking code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for your help. One last question. I have a time limit of 100 ms for UDP message and 200 ms for TCP message. Will this be possible with asynchronous method?

Comment: It depends on what else your code is doing, you would have to try and find out.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ok I'll try it first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning** Using multiple threads to send/receive with socket would lock the sockets and its I/O operation in your program.

When you are working with sockets it's better to work with async that sockets provide, like `BeginRead` and 'EndRead', because they make that the program will run over the same thread and it avoids the socket-client would get blocked. Also, don't use sleep into the socket-clients, they will block the socket.

Check this answer: [C# High CPU usage on Listener thread, sleeping misses disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327534/c-sharp-high-cpu-usage-on-listener-thread-sleeping-misses-disconnect/43332998#43332998)

In this answer i show how to use use the `BeginRead` and `WriteRead`.