# A continuous async client socket receiving example c#

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, client

I've seen different approaches to Sockets and want to go with something newer (.Net 4.5 and above)/easier to maintain and read.

Basic requirements for the client receiving method:

- 1) Has to be continuously connected to a server (and waiting for
  messages 24/7)
- 2) Minimize resources during this time
- 3) The server response will be processed and displayed to a Win Form
- 4) *Bonus* Properly detect if the socket is disconnected and needs to
  reconnect

My preference would be to have a Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) example that can handle multiple messages, but not a while(true) to eat up CPU time. Any good concrete examples out there for what I want to do?

This article:
[Continuously receive from Async socket in c# in a separate Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676543/continuously-receive-from-async-socket-in-c-sharp-in-a-separate-thread)
is along the lines of what I'm thinking, but I figured I would solicit some opinions and examples. SignalR is not an option as suggested in that post.

Comment: seems like a homework

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i answered a similar question about it, let me shared it:

[C# High CPU usage on Listener thread, sleeping misses disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327534/c-sharp-high-cpu-usage-on-listener-thread-sleeping-misses-disconnect/43332998#43332998)

The idea is using one single thread to avoid block sockets, using async methods. Using asynchronous sockets you improve the use of resources.