# C# TCP Client in new thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcplistener

I have a TcpListener listening for incoming connections, and now i basically want to ask if it is better to process the client communication in the same thread or start a new one; so if there is a best practice.

I intentionally didn't add the try-catch blocks and other handling to keep the question simple and clear.

Method 1:

```
while(true)
{
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    processData(client);
}
```

Method 2:

```
while(true)
{
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    new Thread(() => processData(client)).Start();
}
```

Method 3:

```
while(true)
{
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    Thread t = new Thread(() => processData(client));
    t.Start();
    t.Join();
}
```

The code was written like Method 1 before, but `processData` randomly threw `ThreadAbortException`s, which shut down the entire server thread (probably because of some timeout with the client, could not exactly find the source of the Exception as the code runs on a .NET Compact framework on an Embedded Compact 2013 machine).

Comment: The answer is: it depends.

Comment: its technically a broad questions, however... personally I would possibly look at using different threads otherwise you are stuck to the single thread and everything else will be queued and waiting for the operation to finish

Comment: As a side note: In method 1, a second client can be processed until first one is finished.

Comment: Thread-per-client doesn't tend to scale well. Ideally, you use the built in async points to do neither of your options, but instead only implicitly "borrow" threads from the I/O pool when data is actually available to use.

Comment: I would use one thread.  The listener is designed to automatically up to 100 connections at one time.  In the Accept method a new socket is passed for each new connection.  Once you get then socket you can create a separate thread to process each socket in the async accept event.  But the main code should be a single thread.  So never solution is correct.  See the msdn example for sockets.  The socket class can be replaced with any class the inherits the socket like TcpClient.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: updated my question, is method 3 better because it allows only one client at a time?

Answer (score 1):

> i basically want to ask if it is better to process the client communication in the same thread or start a new one; so if there is a best practice.

When you are using threads with sockets you could block the I/O channels each time that the thread which handle the socket is paused. And, your first case is better than third case, because you the program doesn't need to change of thread.

So, in my experience, the best way to process multiple socket is using a single thread and its asyncrhonous methods. It is faster and secure than multiple threads by sockets. With this technic you are optimize the machine resources and avoid the threads competing for them.

Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327534/c-sharp-high-cpu-usage-on-listener-thread-sleeping-misses-disconnect/43332998#43332998) to see how to use asynchronous methods into the socket. In this case I attended 15k socket request by hour and the the use of the processor does not exceed 1%.